# SQL Server : stuck in WHILE loop using @@fetch_status

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, sql-server-2008

I have tried to update the mtrl table using while loop with `@@fetch_status` but it looks that something is happen and there is an infinite loop.

When I run the following code in SQL Server, it gets stuck.

Any idea what is going wrong?

```
USE [TEST_DB]
GO

SET ANSI_NULLS ON
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

BEGIN
    declare @iteid int;

    SET NOCOUNT ON;
    Declare items cursor for
        select mtrl 
        from mtrl 
        where sodtype = 51 and company = 1 and socurrency = 1;

    open items;

    fetch next from items into @iteid;

    while @@fetch_status = 0
    begin
        update mtrl
        set pricer = 2
        where mtrl = @iteid;
    end

    close items;
    deallocate items;
END
GO
```

Comment: You forgot another `fetch next from items into @iteid;` before `end`, after your `update` statement.

Comment: Thank you so much for the fast answer! this solve my problem!!

Comment: Not so fast! Please check my answer. You should not be using a `CURSOR` for this simple task.

Comment: Ok @FelixPamittan Thank you so much!! :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You forgot to add another `FETCH` statement inside your `WHILE` loop:

```
open items;
fetch next from items into @iteid;

while @@fetch_status=0
begin
    update mtrl
    set pricer=2
    where mtrl = @iteid;

    fetch next from items into @iteid;
end
```

However, seeing your query, you should not be using a `CURSOR` for this simple task:

```
update mtrl
    set pricer = 2
where
    sodtype = 51
    and company = 1
    and socurrency = 1;
```